# Linux Bash: extracting text from file int variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I haven't found anything that clearly answers my question. Although very close, I think...

I have a file with a line:

```
# Skipsdata for serienummer 1158
```

I want to extract the 4 digit number at the end and put it into a variable, this number changes from file to file so I can't just search for "1158". But the "# Skipsdata for serienummer" always remains the same.

I believe that either `grep`, `sed` or `awk` may be the answer but I'm not 100 % clear on their usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Awk` as

```
numberRequired=$(awk '/# Skipsdata for serienummer/{print $NF}' file)
printf "%s\n" "$numberRequired"
1158
```

Comment: Right and for the OP - Next time show your target line in context with other lines and show the expected output plus what you've tried. See [ask].

Comment: will this save the white space between serienummer and 1158 into the variable?

Comment: @RobbieAggas: Why do you need the white-space between them? This just stores the number

Comment: @RobbieAggas and THAT is why it's important to specify the expected output in your question because when you don't we're just guessing and I don't think anyone guessed you wanted the white space saved. Edit your question to show us exactly what some concise, testable sample input and expected output would be for your problem.

Comment: @Inian I DONT want the white space just wanting to be clear.

Comment: @RobbieAggas: This DOES NOT store the white-space, try it once and see it for yourself

Comment: Great thanks everyone, this was def the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with the `-o` switch, which prints only the matched part instead of the whole line.

Print all numbers at the end of lines from file `yourFile`

```
grep -Po '\d+$' yourFile
```

Print all four digit numbers at the end of lines like described in your question:

```
grep -Po '^# Skipsdata for serienummer \K\d{4}$' yourFile
```

`-P` enables perl style regexes which support `\d` and especially `\K`.
`\d` matches any digit (0-9).
`\d{4}` matches exactly four digits.
`\K` lets grep forget the previously matched part, such that only the part afterwards is printed.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this idea, the file has many other lines in it with numbers. I'm just looking to find this line and take the four digit number at the end.

Comment: @RobbieAggas I think you read an old version of my answer. Sorry for posting that version in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find your number. Assuming the input data is in a file called `inputfile`:

`mynumber=$(sed -n 's/# Skipsdata for serienummer //p' <inputfile)` will print only the number and ignore all the other lines;

`mynumber=$(grep '^# Skipsdata for serienummer' inputfile | cut -d ' ' -f 5)` will filter the relevant lines first, then only output the 5th field (the number)

Comment: so from what youre saying:

mynumber=$(grep '^# Skipsdata for serienummer' inputfile | cut -d ' ' -f 5)
echo $mynumber

will result:

1158